# Finding Kosher Fruit Flavored Snacks

Tags: food, kashrut-kosher, product-recommendation

Anyone know of a kosher fruit flavored snack, similar to [these](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001G8YFQK)? According to oukosher.org there exists a "Scooby-Doo! Fruit Flavored Snacks 10 Count Carton" that is OU Parve, but I cannot find it anywhere. I did not see any results on ok.org. We are looking for a fruit flavored snack that is tasty. Not of the 100% whole fruit variety. Thanks.

Comment: Is [this](http://www.amazon.com/Fruit-Shapes-Flavored-10-Count-Pouches/dp/B000EMOCTE) what was described on oukosher.org?

Comment: So one would think. I don't see a any certification on the box image. I also saw that exact box at a local grocer, no certification on it anywhere. I feel like they ran a select run of the items or sell it to select store(s).

Comment: do you specifically want "scooby doo" snacks?

Answer (score 2):

Not healthy, but [Gushers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000EMK48W) were kosher, last time I checked.

Comment: Tasty non-fruit-based candy is unlikely to be healthy.

Comment: @DoubleAA: he did say: _Not of the 100% whole fruit variety_

Comment: Thanks Menachem. They are kosher. Hoping to find something more like a gummy bear, but not a gummy bear.

Answer (score 1):

Besides [Gushers](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/28754), Fruit by the Foot and Fruit Roll-Ups were kosher last I checked. All three are made by [General Mills](http://www.generalmills.com/Home/Brands/Snacks/Fruit%20Snacks/Brand%20Product%20List%20Page.aspx).

Comment: Thanks msh210. All true. Which is why I don't understand they don't make kosher fruit snacks. The Fruit roll-ups are close to the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Jelly Belly fruit snacks has an OU on it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about availability where you live, but here in Texas, Gedilla Fruit Snacks are a good kosher choice and they're also kosher l'Pesach.

Answer (score -1):

Walmart's "Great Value" brand smily faces is k.

Comment: I'm sorry; it's been pointed out to me that "great value" is the name of a brand.   I'll edit your answer to be more clear about that.  If you can [edit] in  how you know this to be the case, that would make this answer more valuable.  Thanks!